# Could not initialize class JdbcSynonymFilterFactory

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, solr, solrcloud

I'm new to solr, I want to add a field type with JdbcSynonymFilter and JdbcStopFilter to solr schema. I added my data source same as instruction in this link: [Loading stopwords from Postgresql to Solr6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43724758/loading-stopwords-from-postgresql-to-solr6?noredirect=1#comment74559858_43724758)

then i configured managed-schema with code below:

```
<fieldType name="new_string" class="solr.TextField">
     <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s]+" />
        <filter class="com.s24.search.solr.analysis.jdbc.JdbcSynonymFilterFactory"   
           sql="SELECT concat(term, '=>', use) as line FROM thesaurus;" 
           dataSource="jdbc/dsTest" ignoreCase="false" expand="true" />
        <filter class="com.s24.search.solr.analysis.jdbc.JdbcStopFilterFactory"   
        sql="SELECT stopword FROM stopwords" 
        dataSource="jdbc/dsTest"/>
     </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

I added solr-jdbc to dist folder, postgressql driver, beanutils and  dbutils to contrib/jdbc/lib folder. Then, I included libs in solrconfig.xml of data_driven_schema_configs:

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/jdbc/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-jdbc-\d.*\.jar" />
```

I encountered the following error when I was trying to start SolrCloud.

> "Could not initialize class com.s24.search.solr.analysis.jdbc.JdbcSynonymFilterFactory,trace=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.s24.search.solr.analysis.jdbc.JdbcSynonymFilterFactory"

Comment: I appreciate your help @freedev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm one of the developer from the solr-jdbc project, tried to integrate our project into the current solr version 6.5.1 and followed these steps:

1. Download solr zip and extract it
2. Place your fieldtype into the managed-schema file: ~/.../solr-6.5.1/example/example-DIH/solr/solr/conf

```html
<fieldType name="new_string" class="solr.TextField">
   <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s]+" />
      <filter class="com.s24.search.solr.analysis.jdbc.JdbcSynonymFilterFactory"   
         sql="SELECT concat(term, '=>', use) as line FROM thesaurus;" 
         dataSource="jdbc/dsTest" ignoreCase="false" expand="true" />
      <filter class="com.s24.search.solr.analysis.jdbc.JdbcStopFilterFactory"   
         sql="SELECT stopword FROM stopwords" 
         dataSource="jdbc/dsTest"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

3. Add the following line to: ~/.../solr-6.5.1/example/example-DIH/solr/solr/conf/solrconfig.xml

```html
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-jdbc-2.3.7.jar" />
```

4. Compile the unpacked solr-jdbc release: Run "mvn clean install" in the solr-jdbc-2.3.7 folder
5. Place the compiled jar (solr-jdbc-2.3.7/target/solr-jdbc-2.3.7.jar) into the ~/.../solr-6.5.1/dist/ folder
6. Run the Solr DIH example "~/.../solr-6.5.1/bin/solr -e dih"

Now there is no **NoClassDefFound** exception.

After that you have to create a jndi resource in your jetty and everything should run fine.

Greetings,
Tobias